# Servicenow - Using a variable in a workflow which was selected in the request

Tags: workflow, servicenow

I am currently learning to create workflows. Now I want to create tasks based on the item someone requests in my shop.

For example, Peter buys a mobile phone. From a reference field in the shop he selects an Iphone 3. Now someone should bring him the Iphone 3. So my Workflow attached to the order is a simple task which takes the referenced Item which Peter selected. How can I achieve this using workflows?

I googled and watched some youtube videos, but somehow I didn't find a good match for my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer myself. To use a variable from the catalog you need to use "create catalog task", this option is available when create the workflow on the request item table (sc_req_item). Otherwise you can only create a "create task" element which will not have the option to pick any of your created variables.